# TCP Server accepting() connections when no connection is being made

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, server, network-programming

**EDIT: The issue has been found. Another service was running on the network using the same port number.**

The following server code running on a Pi 4 under Raspbian Buster Lite (Debian 10) will accept() connections and receive data sent by the client and return a response to the client. However, while sitting at accept() waiting for a connection it will, on very regular basis, think a connection was made and read the same three bytes (0x1D 0x6E 0x02).

Here's some sample output:

```
pi@bps-dev:~/source $ ./a.out
Waiting for connection....
Connection established
1B 40 1B 1B 1B 40 1B 2E 00 45 4C 00 92 49 24 92   .@...@...EL..I$.
49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49   I$.I$.I$.I$.I$.I
24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24   $.I$.I$.I$.I$.I$
92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92   .I$.I$.I$.I$.I$.
49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49   I$.I$.I$.I$.I$.I
24 0A 0D 1B 2E 00 45 4C 00 49 24 92 49 24 92 49   $.....EL.I$.I$.I
24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24   $.I$.I$.I$.I$.I$
92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92   .I$.I$.I$.I$.I$.
49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49   I$.I$.I$.I$.I$.I
24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 0A 0D   $.I$.I$.I$.I$...
1B 2E 00 45 4C 00 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24   ...EL.$.I$.I$.I$
92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92   .I$.I$.I$.I$.I$.
49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49   I$.I$.I$.I$.I$.I
24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24   $.I$.I$.I$.I$.I$
92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 24 92 49 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A   .I$.I$.I$.I.....
0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 1B   ................
76                                                v
Waiting for connection....
Connection established
1D 6E 02                                          .n.
Waiting for connection....
Connection established
1D 6E 02                                          .n.
Waiting for connection....
Connection established
1D 6E 02                                          .n.
Waiting for connection....
Connection established
1D 6E 02                                          .n.
Waiting for connection....
Connection established
1D 6E 02                                          .n.
Waiting for connection....
```

Notice all the "connection established" established messages. I'm pretty sure nothing is actually connecting. Though I haven't verified with tcpdump.

Neither accept() nor read() ever return an error. ***What could be happening?***

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PORT 9100
#define READ_CHUNK_SIZE         (1024)  /* read data in 1k blocks */


int msleep(long msec)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    int res;

    if (msec < 0)
    {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }

    ts.tv_sec = msec / 1000;
    ts.tv_nsec = (msec % 1000) * 1000000;

    do
    {
        res = nanosleep(&ts, &ts);
    } while (res && errno == EINTR);

    return res;
}


void DEBUG_DumpMem( uint8_t *buffer, int length )
{
    int x;
    unsigned long bytes = 0;
    char outbuf[80];
    int hex_pos, asc_pos;
    uint8_t *ptr;
    int i;

    ptr = buffer;   
    hex_pos = 0;
    asc_pos = 50;
    memset(outbuf, ' ', sizeof(outbuf)-1);
    outbuf[79] = 0x00;
    for(i = 0; i<length; i++)
    {
            x = *(ptr+i);
            sprintf(&outbuf[hex_pos], "%02X ", x);
            outbuf[asc_pos++] = ( x >= 0x20 && x <= 0x7e ) ? (char)x : '.';

            outbuf[hex_pos+=3] = ' ';

            if(!((++bytes)%16))
            {
                printf("%s\n", outbuf);
                hex_pos = 0;
                asc_pos = 50;

                memset( outbuf, ' ', sizeof(outbuf)-1);
            }
    }
    printf("%s\n", outbuf);
}

uint8_t *SocketRead(int sockfd, int *bytesRead, int timeout)
{
    int size_recv = 0;
    int total_size = 0;
    struct timeval begin;
    struct timeval now;
    uint8_t *data = NULL;
    double timediff;

    // initially we will provide ourselves with a 275k buffer
    // which is more than large enough for a 3" x 8" rasterized image.
    data = malloc((size_t)READ_CHUNK_SIZE * 275);

    if( data != NULL )
    {
        // do first read without regard to timeout
        total_size = read(sockfd, data, READ_CHUNK_SIZE);
        if( total_size > 0 )
        {
            gettimeofday(&begin , NULL);
            while(1)
            {
                gettimeofday(&now , NULL);

                timediff = (now.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec) + 1e-6 * (now.tv_usec - begin.tv_usec);

                //received data and we hit our timeout. We will assume all data
                //has been read.
                if( total_size > 0 && timediff > timeout )
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if( timediff > timeout)
                {
                    // no data received and timeout occurred
                    break;
                }

                // TODO: We need to at some point make sure to realloc() the buffer if we have to read more than
                // 275k of data
                if((size_recv =  recv(sockfd, &data[total_size], READ_CHUNK_SIZE, MSG_DONTWAIT) ) > 0)
                {
                    total_size += size_recv;
                }
                msleep(100);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if( total_size == -1 )
            {
                perror("read:");
            }
        }
    }

    *bytesRead = total_size;
    return data;
}



// This is the entry point upon which all processing and communication is done
// with the K20 docking board. It is expected that when this function returns the
// client is sent a response and the socket has been closed.
void HandleConnection(int sockfd)
{
    char response[] = "Status: Unknown";
    int bytesRead = 0;
    uint8_t *clientData = NULL;

    clientData = SocketRead(sockfd, &bytesRead, 2);
    DEBUG_DumpMem( clientData, bytesRead);
    free(clientData);

    // send response to client
    write(sockfd, response, sizeof(response));
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    socklen_t len;
    int sockfd, connfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, client;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd == -1)
    {
        perror("create socket:");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&servaddr, 0x00, sizeof(servaddr));

    // set IP and port number
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    int reuse = 1;
    if(setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*)&reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0)
    {
        perror("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed");
    }

    if ((bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))) != 0)
    {
        perror("bind:");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((listen(sockfd, 5)) != 0)
    {
        perror("listen:");
        exit(1);
    }

    len = (socklen_t)sizeof(client);
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Waiting for connection....\n");

        // Accept the data packet from client and verification
        connfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &len);
        if (connfd < 0)
        {
            //if(errno == EINTR)
            //{
            //  continue;
            //}
            perror("acccept:");
            //exit(1);
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Connection established\n");
        }

        // Do all of the printing processing stuff in the function.
        // When this function returns the socket will be closed and another connection
        // can be accepted in the loop.
        HandleConnection(connfd);
    }
    close(sockfd);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Does it still happen if you change the port number?

Comment: It is unlikely that no connection is made, but likely no connection from your client. Port 9100 is for raw printing so it might be some other device. Check the source IP of the client which is returned by accept to narrow down what is making these connections.

Comment: I found out that is was in fact some other service running on the network using the same port number!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with the code that was causing the issue. It was in fact another service running on the network using the same port.

Comment: You only call `len` before calling `accept` the first time. You need to set it each time.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz will `len` actually change?

Comment: It can if you ever receive an address that's shorter than the maximum address size. You pass it in the amount of space and it passes out the actual size.